# Web GL for Intel HD Graphics

Tags: graphics, intel

Web GL works well in Firefox(version 11.0) but does not in Google Chrome (ver.17.0.963)
(Error in Chrome= your graphics card doesn't support webgl)

Specs- Core i5 650
       Intel HD graphics
       4GB DDR3 RAM

(but it works well in win7)

Comment: You need to supply more information if you want an answer.  How do you know that WebGL is causing the problem?  What graphics chip, processor, and memory do you have?  Have you tested this on another computer and gotten the same results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `chrome://flags/`.

Enable "ignore software rendering blacklist" or in version 22+ "Override software rendering"

This works for me.

Comment: @Mitch The Chromium and Google Chrome browsers use links that start with `chrome://` to expose information and settings pertaining to the local browser installation. The link in this answer is not a link to another source providing advice. Rather, this answer is self-contained, and that link is part of the instructions it provides. Short answers that contain links should not *automatically* be assumed to be unsummarized links to external help sources. (It's best not to assume that even when the link starts with `http://` or `https://`, as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing mesa-utils it should work. This works on my i3 with intel HD 2000

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```